# Serve several mercurial repositories on the same server

Tags: mercurial

I have a following question. We are currently trying to select an appropriate structure for our development. What we are trying to achieve is the following:

- There is a central repository in Mercurial that we have - let's call it A.
- There are also repositories in Mercurial that are the children of A - repositories B, C, and D (for each developer).
- Each of these repositories has a hook binding it to Hudson.
- Hudson has several jobs (for each developer) - it generates a build and deploys it on the test server in the catalog for the concrete developer that made a push to it's own repository.
- Therefore each developer can play with his own repository and make pushes to the central one only about once in a week.

The question is how to host all those repositories on a single server. I want something like:

- http://server:8000/central
- http://server:8000/developer1
- http://server:8000/developer2
- ...etc

In that way I can create scripts in Hudson for each repository and that way the jobs of one developer will not affect the other in any way, nor will the testing of EARs overlap, since every developer will get his own EAR generated and deployed.

UPD. Thanks to everyone for answering. Now we use the following structure.

- The central repository is hosted at 8000 port with **hg serve** command.
- As for the personal developer repositories, they were created by cloning from central repository and then hosted on 8001 port with the help of hgweb.cgi (watch this [tutorial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/HgWebDirStepByStep)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look into configuring hgwebdir.cgi for Apache:

https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/HgWebDirStepByStep

That is how we have ours set up, it's super easy (it's child's play compared to Apache SVN setup), but if you have any problems come back with an edit.

Of course we host ours on https://myHgServer/hg/repo1, repo2, etc. but that is all apache configs.

We combine this with phpHgAdmin for easy administrative access and configuration of repos.

Comment: Thanks, by the way, how can we serve like this a parent and a child repo. Suppose I have two repositories hg/repo1 and hg/repo2, and the second one is created as the clone of the first - clone repo1 repo2, will it work on the server, will the programmer on his own machine be able to clone the second repo and push to it with no problems?

Comment: You'll have to make a new repo on the server and have the programmer push his local clone to it, or you can do the clone on the server and have the programmer pull the clone.

Answer (score 5):

As well as hgwebdir.cgi, it's worth looking at [Rhodecode](http://rhodecode.org/). It's a web app for mercurial that supports pull and push, but also does things like fork management on the server (like bitbucket, or git-hub) It's also really nice for exploring changesets, or files, but for you it's the developers being able to set-up their own forks on the server that I think would be the main selling point.

A bit more heavy weight than hgwebdir. Installation is a little more complex (It's written in Pylons, so it's fcgi or wsgi), but it's still pretty simple. I had a test server up in an hour.

Comment: Wow you deserve the answer, checked out RhodeCode and it's replacing our system, it's like a miniature Bitbucket, its great!

Comment: Pylons and RhodeCode it's not only fcgi(really not recommend this one) or wsgi, It works also with proxy-pass and built in paster serve can be used to serve the whole thing even without http server.